# How can I export a PDF from GIMP with each layer on a new page?

Tags: pdf, gimp, image-processing

I have multiple layers open in GIMP. I would like to export a pdf that has each layer on a new page.

Comment: [We are allowed to answer our own questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: It's not *just allowed*, it's [actually encouraged](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/16747/downvotes-for-answering-own-questions) :)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

GIMP (prior to 2.10) can't do this directly.

You need to use an intermediate file format.

#### Prerequisites

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

#### Steps

1. Export from GIMP as an MNG animation: `File` → `Export` → `document.mng`
2. Convert to PDF on the terminal:

   ```
   convert -reverse document.mng document.pdf
   ```

Comment: Nice tweak for not having to reorder the layers from how they come in from a pdf in the import.

Comment: Gimp 2.10 can do this, see @mjoao 's answer

Comment: -reverse also needs a new version of convert; 1.3.23 does not do that.

Comment: On Ubuntu, if you get "not authorized" see accepted answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1081895/trouble-with-batch-conversion-of-png-to-pdf-using-convert

Answer (score 64):

**Gimp (2.10) does it already.** No extra software or plugins needed.

1. Import all images/pages as layers.
2. Go to *File → Export As → filename.pdf*.
3. After clicking *Export As*, a dialog will pop up asking to confirm save options. Select *Layers as pages* and *Reverse the pages order*.
4. Click the <kbd>Export</kbd> button.

That's all! Enjoy.

Comment: Not only does GIMP do this built in, but it's even clever enough that if you want to have multiple layers make up a page e.g. a base image and various additional text layers - you can do this using layer groups and then with the 'Layers as pages' option, GIMP will export each layer group as a separate page!

Comment: The installed GIMP I have on Ubuntu 16.04 (GIMP 2.8.16) does not have this option.

Comment: GIMP 2.8.18 does not have this option

Comment: You don't need to reverse pages order if images were imported in order (last page as top layer)

Comment: You have to CLICK EXPORT first to see these options in #3

Comment: No it doesn.t. Even after clicking on export, there is no such am option

Comment: Sorry using Gimp 2.8.22 still has not the "export layers as pages" option.
In fact, I did not start importing a pdf but had separate images from photographing a multipage document with a smartphone. So I opened those separately and pasted all together into one stack of layers. The export as mng and the convert did the job for me (see next answer).

Comment: One feature this built-in export is missing is using lossy compression for this PDF export.

Comment: Is there a way to export based on **layer groups**?
I asked also the question [here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/154846).

Answer (score 1):

There is a Gimp plugin that does this nicely.

http://registry.gimp.org/node/27987

The install path and how to change the permissions are covered in this blog post: https://www.zyxware.com/articles/4438/how-to-export-multiple-layers-from-gimp-into-a-pdf-file

Comment: The link above is currently dead (along with the whole registry). You can get the file here for the moment (from an archive):
https://github.com/pixlsus/registry.gimp.org_static/blob/master/registry.gimp.org/files/export_layers_pdf-0.2.py.txt