# GIMP-2.8 not exporting multiple pages in my PDF

Tags: pdf, gimp

I'm able to export the top layer to pdf using gimp, but unable to get the second layer to be the second page. Watched a lot of tutorials and not sure how to get gimp to save the multiple layers as multiple pages.

here are my layers

[link to screenshot of gimp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f47Ls.png)

but when I export this I only get a pdf of one layer

Comment: I don't think 2.8 supports that natively - see for example [How can I export a PDF from GIMP with each layer on a new page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913761/how-can-i-export-a-pdf-from-gimp-with-each-layer-on-a-new-page) - there used to be a couple of 3rd party plugins, but I'm not clear what happened to them after the old registry went offline

Comment: do you know of any plugins that will do this?

Comment: Not personally - a bit of googling finds this [gimp-forum thread](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Export-multiple-layers-as-a-layered-PDF-not-a-mulitpage-PDF) - there's a link to a zip of a plugin in the first reply. Otherwise, your option is to upgrade to 2.10 I think

Comment: @steeldriver just upgraded and it worked!! if you wanna suggest it I will mark as a fix and upvote :)

Comment: Glad that worked for you - I think we should mark it as a duplicate instead since that's one of the solutions proposed on the linked thread. You can upvote [the answer there](https://askubuntu.com/a/1098603/178692)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I export a PDF from GIMP with each layer on a new page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913761/how-can-i-export-a-pdf-from-gimp-with-each-layer-on-a-new-page)